# During a workflow, restrict fields from being edited based on field value

Tags: workflow

This requirement appears so obvious there's probably an easy way which I'm sure you could point me to.

Given a workflow, after a particular point (based on a Picklist field, `Status`) I want certain fields to disabled *with the edit icon not being visible*.

I am progressing the state of the workflow field `Status` using *Flows*, so have opportunity to do something there.

Comment: If this is a custom object, lightning dynamic forms might be another option : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms_ga.htm&release=228&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I'll have a look at that. Record Types aren't really working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this, though not elegant or sufficient.

The trick is to create TWO instances of each field, with one being Read-only. Apply mutually exclusive Visibility conditions to them so they are only editable based on this condition (eg. State >= "For Review").

This requires that the User profile your users are members of do *not* have *Can edit read-only fields*.

This does not work for fields marked as *Required* in their definition. You have to come up with another way to achieve this.

I have no words why this is made so difficult. Feels a mainstream requirement.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the record type at that point, which will then allow you to show a different page layout that will display these fields as read only.

Comment: That's where my next thought was. Some more flailing required, thanks for pointing me in that direction. I definitely welcome any other ideas.